# Is it possible to set a URL image on the tablayout icon?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a tablayout on HomeActivity, and it has a static icon. I would like to know if it is possible and how to make so that in this icon, the user's photo is shown. It comes through a URL.

Here is the code for Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

    binding.search.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            startActivity(Intent(this@HomeActivity, SearchActivity::class.java))
        }
    })

    binding.tabLayout.addTab(binding.tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_message_24dp))
    binding.tabLayout.addTab(binding.tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_history_24dp))
    binding.tabLayout.addTab(binding.tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_people_24dp))
    binding.tabLayout.addTab(binding.tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_settings_24dp))

    pagerAdapter = HomePagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, binding.tabLayout.tabCount)

    binding.viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
    binding.viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(binding.tabLayout))
    binding.tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
            binding.viewPager.currentItem = tab.position
        }

        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
    })

    //registerMessagesObserver()
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

    }
}
```

The icon in question would be the `binding.tabLayout.addTab (binding.tabLayout.newTab().SetIcon(R.drawable.ic_settings_24dp))`

Comment: @fmaccaroni Maybe you're right. What do I do now? Can I withdraw my question?

Comment: you can either delete it if you want or leave it and some moderator will see the flag and decide whether it is indeed a duplicate or not

Comment: @fmaccaroni If you want to reply, I'll mark it. Because this post solved my problem.

Comment: just vote that post, it's the right thing to do when is a duplicate :D